# Check how many packets are being received by each interface/computer on the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, terminal, shell, packet

Is there a way I can check via terminal or command line how many packets are being received by each interface/computer on the network?

I want to check which PC is downloading a large amount of data.

Comment: What is the make and model of the device they are connected to?  Or do you want to check each one - if so, what operating systems are they running?

Comment: @Paul Each one of them is connected to a wireless router through their laptops or mobile phones. Wireless router is then connected to internet

Comment: This didn't answer either of my questions :)

Comment: If you check the interfaces, you'll also see local traffic and will have no good way to separate it from Internet traffic. I think what you really want to do is get traffic statistics from your router.

Comment: @Paul then i didn't understand your question

Comment: The device they are connected to is a wireless router.  What make and model is it.  What operating systems are the laptops and phones that  connect running?  I am not sure how to phrase these questions differently.

Comment: @Paul linux,windows,android. there are hp,lenovo laptops. But why do you want these ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta because you will either gather the information from the OS or from the wireless router, which you have still not provided the details of.

Comment: @Paul It is fedora 16,ubuntu 11,windows7,windows xp,android gingerbread

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use [SNMP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324263) and [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/).

SNMP will report you current state of interface bandwidth.

[Linux tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/nixcraft/linux/docs/uniqlinuxfeatures/mrtg/mrtg_config_step_3.php)

[Windows tutorial](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-nt-guide.en.html)